How to do a tbl_cross with survey data that has a column for weight?
I need to do a cross tab using survey data and print the table using gtsummary. The survey data has an id column as well as a column for sampling weight.
When I used tbl_svy_summary, it produced a characteristics table with unweighted and weighted frequencies, but I could not find how to do a tbl_cross. Please see image: enter image description here
In the image, you can see that the totals add up to 100% vertically within each column and p-values correspond to that. What I need is to be able to cross tab each row across the columns.
For example, I need for each row under "Age", I need the weighted and unweighted frequencies **across ** Unvaccinated, Undervaccinated, and UTD, (100% adding horizontally) and the associated p-value for it.
My code using the tbl_svy_summary is below:
svy_df <-
  survey::svydesign(
    id = ~id,
    weights = ~weight,
    data = df
  )

svy_df %>%
  tbl_svysummary(
    # stratify summary statistics by the "both" column
    by = HPV_VACCINATION_STATUS,
    # summarize a subset of the columns
    include = c(AGE,...(other columns)..,HPV_VACCINATION_STATUS),
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n_unweighted} | {n} ({p}%)"),
  ) %>%
  add_p()

I also looked at survey package and found that I could create a crosstab using svytable (see code below for a couple of variables), but then how do I use the resulting svytable with gtsummary, so I can easily run it for crosstab p-values and a professional-looking table. I have about 13 such crosstabs to run.
tl <- survey::svytable(~AGE+HPV_VACCINATION_STATUS, svy_df)
t2 <- survey::svytable(~STATE+HPV_VACCINATION_STATUS, svy_df)

`
